# xcode 10 coreplot messaging unqualified id

Tags: core-plot, xcode10

I am using Xcode10 and Core-Plot 2.3. 
When compiling I keep getting the following errors on CPTTradingRangePlot file.

1) Messaging unqualified ID
2) Implicit Conversion from nullable pointer 'NSNumber * _Nullable' to non-nullable pointer type 'ObjectType _Nonnull' (aka 'id')

Any ideas. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't see any compile errors in that file with the version on the `release-2.3` branch. How are you incorporating Core Plot into your app? Are you certain you have the 2.3 branch and not an older version?

Answer (score 3):

```
GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0
```

add the config in the bulid setting as shown here:

[image]